# Pattern matching in squeryl queries

Tags: scala, orm, squeryl

I have just started with squeryl and have no answer for how write a query like that

```
SELECT ref label 
FROM x_table 
WHERE ref like x% or lable like x%
```

where `x` is some value from the user, especially I haven't found analog of the sign `%`  in squeryl or how can I use it.

My version:

```
val products = from(AppDB.productTable) (
    s => where ((s.label like value) or (s.ref like value))  select(s)
)
```

doesn't work correct.

`val value : Option[String]` I get from the user.

Comment: Are you asking how to append a `%` character to the end of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to optionize your fields, like this:

```
val products = from(AppDB.productTable) (s => 
  where ((Some(s.label) like value) or (Some(s.ref) like value)) 
  select(s))
```

That will compile as the query will be comparing an Option[String] to an Option[String]. Squeryl will handle the option state internally.

If you are simply looking to add the wildcard to what you are comparing, assuming both sides of the like clause are of the type `Option[String]`, then you can do this:

```
s.label like value.map(_ + "%")
```

Comment: No in this case we get an erorr **like is not a member of Some[Option[String]]**...

Comment: `s.ref` is an `Option[String]` and `value` is an `Option[String]`? What was the error you were receiving originally?

Comment: Yes, I was looking how to add the wildcard, so that is ok, thanks, but it works only with _Option[String]_ and will not work with _String_ for example right?

Comment: as for the code @jcern suggested in the top of the answer, it gives an error **"like is not a member of Some[Option[String]]"**

Comment: If value was a string, you could simply make the right hand side `(value + "%")`.

Comment: No the value was `Option[String]` and it's OK with Map(),I asked so, because applying map to Option[String] and String gives different results. `(value + "%")` should work, but when I was trying so, I haven't got any result, no errors and no result, but now I know why...

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorter version:

```
AppDB.productTable.where ((s.label like value) or (s.ref like value))
```

and option fields are for nullable columns

Comment: No, in this way it doesn't behave as necessary, if you need to get all rows where **label** or **ref** contains **value** you have to use a wild card